# Execute SOQL query via REST API in apex

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api, httprequest

I'm trying to execute an SOQL query via REST API call because I want to retrieve custom labels (ExternalString) previous to a date and by Category.

I generate my query like this

```
Datetime limitDate = Datetime.now();
String query = 'SELECT Name FROM ExternalString WHERE Category = \'Test\' AND LastModifiedDate >= ' + limitDate;
```

And I'm trying this request

```
endpoint = '/services/data/v' + apiversion + '/query/q=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query.replace(' ','+'), 'UTF-8');
HttpResponse result;
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
result = http.send(req);
```

But it's always giving me the following error:

```
no protocol: /services/data/v48.0/query/q=SELECT%2BName%2BFROM%2BExternalString%2BWHERE%2BCategory%2B%3D%2B%27App%2BM%C3%B3vil%27%2BAND%2BLastModifiedDate%2B%3E%3D%2B2021-03-09%2B23%3A00%3A00
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing when trying to achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple things that need fixing

1. You need to use **?q=** in your query. See the example below from the [REST API developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account
```

2. The object you're querying is only available through the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_externalstring.htm) as well so you need to use that endpoint

```
/services/data/v50.0/tooling/query/?q=
```

3. The date value you're using in your filter needs to be in the following format 2021-03-09T00:00:00z

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+ExternalString+WHERE+Category+=+'App+Móvil'+AND+LastModifiedDate+>=2021-03-09T23:00:00z
```

4. You need to pass a session Id in the Authorization header. See [REST Headers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_header_examples.htm) or look at @sfdcfox's tip for using `PageReference` to avoid needing this snippet

```
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

Comment: I'm trying but still gives me the **no protocol error**. This is the endpoint I'm generating: /services/data/v48.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+ExternalString+WHERE+Category+=+'App+Móvil'+AND+LastModifiedDate+>=+'2021-03-09+23:00:00'

Comment: there's actually a couple things I missed - updated answer with the issues I noticed. Was able to query testing in REST explorer in workbench.

Comment: Thanks! But now it's giving me [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]  even though I try the '/services' in workbench and works fine...

Comment: That's to do with the fact you're not passing any session ID which workbench is handling for you. You can click on "Headers" in workbench and see which ones are required . I edited the answer to include this info.

Comment: I'm including this now  `req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('Authorization','Authorization: Bearer '+ UserInfo.getUserId());` but still not working...

Comment: you need to use `UserInfo.getSessionId()`. You got the User Id which is not the same

Comment: @molinet `req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ UserInfo.getSessionId())`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a full URL, as in:

```
String endpoint = 'https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/data/...';
```

If you want to call the local Salesforce server, you can use a PageReference:

```
PageReference ref = new PageReference('/services/data/...');
Blob result = ref.getContent();
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to specify the authorization header, etc.

Comment: I'm trying now but it's giving me a **[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]** but if I pick my endpoint from /services and on it works properly. I'm generating the endpoint with URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + ''/services...' and setting the method as GET. Do I need anything else?

Comment: @molinet If you use HttpRequest, you need to `req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());`

Comment: @molinet Also, why not just use PageReference? Saves you the trouble of using session Id.